# Search and fetch from an API, display clickable results and then show more

Tags: react-native

I am very new to react native and I can init a new project and make a navigation between screens. I can also handle layouts quite okay. But now I want to do more advanced things like search and fetch from an API. I want to display clickable results and then show more but I have no idea how to do it.

Could anyone teach and share some help, please? I have searched a lot but have not found anything yet. This must be a common feature for apps?

API: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json Lets say it has a `"image": "img1.png"` also.

First I want to have a page with a searchbox and a button. If I type "in" there it should show 2 results with an image. There I want to click on each of the titles and it will come to the next page with more info. Should it be done with the id and how?

I understand the code below the line except `renderItem={({item}) => {item.title}, {item.releaseYear}} keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}` what is renderItem doing? Lists every result? How to add more there? Like some views and so on? I tried that but get errors..

What is `keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}` doing?

```
import React from 'react'; 
import { FlatList, ActivityIndicator, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class FetchExample extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){ 
    super(props); 
    this.state ={ 
      isLoading: true
    } 
  }

  componentDidMount(){ 
    return fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json') .then((response) => response.json()) .then((responseJson) => {
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        dataSource: responseJson.movies,
      }, function(){
      });
    })
    .catch((error) =>{
      console.error(error);
    });
  }

  render(){

    if(this.state.isLoading){
      return(
        <View style={{flex: 1, padding: 20}}>
          <ActivityIndicator/>
        </View>
      )
    } else {
      return( 
        <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop:20}}> 
        <FlatList data={this.state.dataSource} renderItem={({item}) => {item.title}, 
        {item.releaseYear}} keyExtractor={(item, index) => index} /> ); } } render(){}
        </View>
    )
    }
  }
}
```

Once upon a time(10 years ago) I knew ASP very well and I still do but I am lost with this. I have just started with apps and read that RN is the hottest. Where should I start? Should I start somewhere else than just read about RN?

Best regards and thank you!

Comment: Firstly, you are rendering incorrectly. I edited your answer to show correct way, but you are passing incorrect props to `FlatList`. Here is all wrong `({item}) => {item.title}, 
        {item.releaseYear}} keyExtractor={(item, index) => index} /> ); } } render(){}` You will need to fix.

Comment: Also, I suggest creating a simple `fetch` application by copying tutorials or watching videos. So you can understand the basics of how react-native works. Or else you will get more lost as I can see from your code snippet/

Comment: Thanks alot for your help. This code is pasted from [link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network) , I thought they are correct. Their code works anyway..

I have been watching many videos and examples and they fetch in many different ways but I haven't found any examples when they search from an api, post it and then makes it clickable.

Comment: Your code is different to the code given in the link. You can follow their tutorial to learn, but if you compare your code to them, yours is very different and wrong.